# Why do we use caret (^) as the symbol for ctrl/control?

Tags: terminology

From my understanding, the caret character (`^`) has been used to indicate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-key combinations since the early UNIX days, if not earlier. Why was this character used to indicate this? Was it simply that the symbol wasn't being used for anything else at the time, or is there an etymological history where that makes sense?

Some things have used alternate notation; for example, Emacs stands out for using `C-` instead, and many user manuals simply write `control-` or `ctrl-`, much as how `alt-` is still commonplace (a notable exception being Apple's modern use of `⌥` for <kbd>Option</kbd>, and similarly `⌘` for <kbd>Command</kbd>, which of course used to be represented with the Apple logo instead, with both open and filled variants on the earliest Apple computers).

The [dictionary definition of caret](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/caret) doesn't make any nod to this usage, and instead only offers:

> a wedge-shaped mark made on written or printed matter to indicate the place where something is to be inserted

and while Wikipedia describes the [usage as a control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#In_ASCII) it states nothing about the history of this usage so far as I can find.

Comment: `⌥` doesn't mean `alt`, it means `option`.  Similarly, `⌘`/`` means `command`.

Comment: @Mark: But `option` has become equivalent to `alt`.  Some Apple keyboards label the key with both; and if you plug a non-Apple keyboard into a Mac, the key labelled `alt` is interpreted as ‘option’.  It may not _originally_ have been the same, but it's now very closely linked.

Comment: FYI, Emacs's use of `C-` comes from the MIT AI Lab, where the [Space Cadet Keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-cadet_keyboard) was popular. It has lots of different modifer keys (Shift, Control, Meta, Super, Hyper) and no one ever came up with punctuation prefixes for them, so they were all notated with abbreviations.

Comment: @gidds Maybe, but on Mac, the key has *never* been officially called Alt. It has always been called *Option*, and after Windows become popular, Apple started printing "alt" on the key as well since the key is used for similar commands as Alt in Windows. But it's definitely, definitely, definitely, the *Option* key. Not Alt. Calling it Alt is incorrect. AFAIK Apple has *never* called it Alt in any marketing or instruction material. (And FWIW they no longer print "alt" on the key.)

Comment: @Mark I was using `Alt` and `Meta` to refer to the commonly-used names of the keys across multiple operating systems (as well as what the actual scancodes are commonly referred to in most keyboard firmware and HID event viewers and the like), and not Apple's own terminology. Also `` is not a universal Unicode codepoint; on Apples it happens to display the Apple logo but it's in the private use area.

Comment: Nonetheless, you incorrectly associated the wrong glyphs.  http://jdebp.uk./FGA/iso-9995-7-symbols.html

Comment: @JdeBP Thanks for the ISO link. I'd never seen that glyph used for `Alt` before nor had I seen the key referred specifically as `Super` rather than `Meta`.

Comment: @JdeBP Great link, but you perhaps should have noted, from it: "USB HID protocol makes no distinction between the left ⌥Option and ⎇ Alt which [are] physically, electrically, and functionally the same key." That is the reason that fluffy is treating the two as the same thing.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

We use caret because the 1968 version of ASCII replaced the perfectly fine up-arrow (previously used for indicating control characters) with a lousy caret, at the same code value.

I think the *up-arrow, letter* convention originated with DEC operating systems.   The primary need was not documentation, but for echoing something printable (and preferably easily recognizable) when a control character is typed on the keyboard.  Bear in mind that the I/O device at this time was something like a teletype.

But I don't think there's anything special about the choice; as far as I known it was a semi-arbitrary decision that stuck.

[This 1965 brochure for the PDP-6 Monitor](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/dec/pdp6/PDP-6_TimsharingBroch.pdf) shows the *uparrow, C* convention for <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, on page 4:

[image: Image from brochure]

Comment: Also, [Caret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation) indicates that the use of `^` was not universal, at least the Acorn used a different notation.

Comment: Also, as far as I can tell from looking around, "control-letter" characters pretty much imply ASCII, at least before PC-style keyboards.  Other codes, say Baudot, had what in modern write-ups get called "control characters", but I don't think they were at the time.  (Note to young people: the world was not originally ASCII, there were many character codes, sometimes even varying between devices on the same system).

Comment: @GregHewgill I suppose Acorn used the shaft of the up-arrow, instead of the head.

Comment: There's a third notation in `printf` in ZSPL, referenced in https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/10936/1932 .

Comment: The caret can serve usefully in most of the roles the up arrow would play, but not vice versa.  Likewise with broken pipe and solid pipe.  Underline versus back-arrow is a more interesting situation.  Underline is certainly useful, and it works just as well as back-arrow for representing a rubbed-out character, but it doesn't really work as well for indicating the *action* of rubbing out a character.

Comment: Left arrow would be a better assignment operator than ```=```, if such a character were common.  The composite ```<-``` is not suitable due to ambiguity of ```x<-1``` : x becomes 1, or x is less than minus 1?

Comment: The main reason for the caret is for internationalization, particularly French and Portuguese. You'd do the caret, backspace, and a letter to get the circumflex. You can't do that with an arrow.

Comment: The original question is why control characters are indicated by "caret, letter", which is surely arbitrary, inasmuch as "up-arrow, letter" was surely arbitrary, and the only difference is how codepoint 0x53 is rendered. Are you talking about my somewhat tongue-in-cheek preference for up-arrow at that codepoint?  I am aware of why caret replaced up-arrow in ASCII, but that doesn't mean I have to like it.

Comment: @another-dave, indeed old ASCII left arrow is used for assignment in the FAIL assembler.  Also on the MIDAS commands line TARGET←SOURCE.

Comment: @another-dave @LarsBrinkhoff The [Casio fx-7500G](https://americanhistory.si.edu/collections/search/object/nmah_1421353) used `→` for assignment.  For example `42→A` stores the value 42 in variable A.

Comment: Incidentally, Prolog and Pascal use `:-` and `:=` respectively because they kinda-sorta resemble left-facing arrows for assignment.