# ZSPL language, anyone heard of it?

Tags: compilers

While reading the Byte sieve article (Gilbreath 1981), I came across a language I have never heard of, ZSPL.

I suspected this was actually a specific version of another language, perhaps PL/1. However, the listing shows it most closely resembling Algol/Pascal.

Has anyone heard of this language before? It does not appear on the wiki nor the taxonomies of languages that I can find.

I have seen references to similar names, but they are not related: there is a zSPL system for programming the C64's SID and another for NonStop systems.

- Jim Gilbreath (September 1981). "[A High-Level Language Benchmark](https://archive.org/details/byte-magazine-1981-09/page/n181)".  *BYTE*.  pp. 180–198.

Comment: It looks Algol-ish, but curiously it has no Boolean type, nor built-in true/false constants.  It has a 'printf' which may indicate it's post-Algol 68 (the first language I know with a procedure called 'printf', as distinct from built-in features like Fortran formats). On the other hand, decimal conversion is "%d" like C, and CR-LF is "&M&J", not like C (and implying ASCII).

Comment: Could you put a link in the question?  It also sounds like some sample code is available; that would also be useful in the question.

Comment: I recommend reading page 198.

Comment: Looks a lot like PLZ/SYS, which was a systems programming language from Zilog. Back in the day, I did a lot of work on Z8000 Unix systems, and I remember the PLZ manual coming with each one. It looked like a cool language but I never had a need to use it.

Comment: It is interesting that the article mentions the language like they doesn't expect that the readers knows the ZSPL language.

Comment: Looks like a home brew language  that didn't take off - pg 198 has a reference to ZSPL - Peter D Ridley, 3321 Byron St, San Diego, CA 92106.  Looks like the home address of the inventor of the language at that time.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Page 198 of that ***Byte*** says ZSPL is by Pete Ridley, whose full name appears to be Peter D Ridley, resident at the time in San Diego, California. He and ZSPL are also briefly mentioned in the December 1981 ***Byte***, but I can't find any other trace of them.

However, the sample ZSPL code looks rather like the [SPL/3000](http://www.hpmuseum.net/exhibit.php?hwdoc=805) programming language, introduced in 1972 by Hewlett-Packard for the HP 3000 business minicomputer. It's lowercase, rather than uppercase, and has some extra keywords. I suspect, although I cannot prove, that ZSPL was an enhanced re-implementation by Ridley of SPL for the Z80 running CP/M, and the "Z" is just from Z80.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like ZSPL is simply a Z-80 implementation, the syntax appears almost identical. Well spotted!

Comment: The logic went "Z doesn't look like the start of an acronym for that period, try SPL as a programming language." There are several, but only SPL/3000 was the right period, and a look at the manual made the idea look very plausible.

Comment: And HP has a history of programming languages matching `?PL` :)